# File Download Functionality in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#

I am having a C# **Windows** Application. I need to implement a functionality to download a CSV Template to User which he/she can fill and upload.

The file needs to be in solution only.

Can anyone suggest me any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried?

Comment: What does "The file needs to be in solution only." mean?

Comment: Here's a few basic guides: [How to: Save Files Using the SaveFileDialog Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx) [How to: Open Files Using the OpenFileDialog Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61097ykx.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to download a File from a specific WebSite use the Webclient class (add a reference to System.Web)

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://mysite.com/myfile.csv", @"c:\Temp\myfile.csv");
```

Comment: The file exists in the soution only. and it is a windows application. This solution looks like for web

Comment: do you want to edit a CSV-File via the UI? what do you mean with solution only? and from where do you want to "download" the csv-file?

Comment: I just want to download it. By solution I mean that file is there in my project only. Not on any server or shared location or URL

Comment: sorry it´s pretty hard to follow you for me...so you already have the csv-file in your project or do you want to download the file to your project? Or do you just want to read the file and not downloading it?